# Are going to get/ are getting married

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if you could help me with this info.

I'm not sure which one is correct between these two. Or if they are both correct, and how can I explain the difference.

They are getting married/ They are going to get married.

Thank you very much.

Comment: ***"are getting married"*** implies either already arranged event or certainty in the future (Try saying **"they are *[definitely]* getting married"** ), whereas ***"be going to"*** sounds to me like a prediction or, even, an alternative to **"will"**, *yet does not sound like a decision made at the moment of speaking.*

Comment: Thank you. The sentence is like this: A: Emma and Nick are going to get/ getting married. B: Really? When?  'Getting' is certain, but does it need a specific time mentioned? I believe it`s a prediction rather than something certain.

Comment: I have to add that your examples can be synonymous with one another, yet the present continuous makes ***a more firm intention*** while in this case. I don't think "getting" sounds like a prediction compared to ***"I am not asking Ann to the party"***, which really is not *a prediction*. In addition to that, ***It's going to rain [soon].*** can sound like a prediction.

Comment: I understand and I agree with you. What I meant in the last sentence was that I will choose 'going to', because in my example, is rather a prediction than something certain.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As a native U.S. speaker, I would call these "mostly" interchangeable in common use.  I see this literally as two equal options of future tense.

Here's the only reason I say "mostly" (vs. 100%):
Say you were at a wedding, currently witnessing it, and someone important is calling you on your mobile phone and asking what you are doing right now. (You would take this in the lobby/vestibule, of course! :D )

At that moment, if you say "Emma and Nick are getting married!" you are speaking in the present tense, informing the caller it is happening literally right now.  In that case, "going to get married" would not work and they would not be interchangeable.

But since I had to contrive that hopefully rare experience, it is merely technical.  Common usage would mean "future" and both work perfectly well with no differences.